# How to import a Javascript library in a List Functions

Tags: javascript, couchdb, couchapp

Is there a way to import "external" Javascript libraries for use in `List Functions` in CouchDB? I am trying to build a `List Function` that will perform a XSL Transformations and I was hoping to be able to use the `Sarissa` library.

**EDIT**: Please see [my related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23215481/xsl-transformations-in-couchdb) about XSL Transformations in CouchDB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to add the source files of the library to your design document. (assuming it's a JS library) How you do that depends on many factors, plus you didn't specify how you're deploying to your CouchDB instance, so I'll just sidestep that for now.

The point is you can share code with list functions (among some others like map functions) as [CommonJS modules](http://couchdb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/query-server/javascript.html#commonjs). If you load the source file into a string that is stored in your design document, you can use the exported library via `require("lib/sarissa")` for example.

Comment: This did not work, when I tried to use jquery. I think because it has no export. How can I import jquery?

Answer (score 1):

If the library is compatible with CommonJS, you can include it with:

```
function(head, req) {
  var Sarissa = require("lib/sarissa");
  ...
}
```

If not, you can include it with `couchapp` precompiler:

```
function(head, req) {
  // !code lib/sarissa.js
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Both answers helped me out, I just had to pick one.