# XSL Transformations in CouchDB

Tags: couchdb

Is it possible to do `XSL Transformations` in a `List Function` in `CouchDB`? Is seems rather improbable, since something like `var xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor()` can't be done outside the context of a browser.

Is there a way?

Comment: Since CouchDB internal format is JSON, a more common use case is to generate XML from JSON in "list" (or "show") functions, and to parse XML to JSON in "update" functions. Why do you need to convert XML to XML?

Comment: I have XML documents stored in CouchDB, that follow slightly different schemas (different versions of the same schema actually). I'd like to use XSLT (I have the .xslt files ready) to "unify" those schemas to the latest version.

Comment: Did you try with a javascript XSLT library?

Comment: I haven't to be honest, but I tried instantiating a `XSLTProcessor` inside a List Function and predictably it failed. All such libraries depend on browser "components" to do the work (ActiveX etc). I'm pretty sure at this point that there is no solution to this.

Comment: And all [NodeJS XSLT libraries](https://www.npmjs.org/search?q=xslt) seem to be wrappers for native libraries and tools. I'm afraid your direction is not the one to follow... As I said earlier, a better solution would be to use XML externally and JSON internally.

Answer (score 0):

If you control the CouchDB server, there's definitely a way. CouchDB supports pluggable query engines, so you could code up a query engine that supports some kind of XSL transformations.

I guess the default SpiderMonkey-based query engine doesn't support it out of the box. I think there's an experimental NodeJS-based query engine floating around that might do better.